# How do I add another checkbox to the php in my contact form?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, contacts

Hi I'm trying to add some another field to this php contact form
I have a checkbox for "do you agree to our terms of business", but how do I add another one for opt in for Marketing.

Thanks for your help

Regards

Judi

```
        <?php
$adminemail = 'lis@blue.co.uk'; // type your actual email address in place of you@yourdomain.com

$usesecimage = ''; // the path to a WSN Links, Gallery, KB or Forum install if you wish to borrow its security image prompt

$autoresponse = ''; // type the URL of a text file which should be used as the autoresponder body text

$controlvars = ' thankspage submitteremail ccsubmitter messagetosubmitter ';
$messagetoadmin = "A user has filled out a form with this content:


";

 if (!isset($_POST['messagetosubmitter'])) $messagetosubmitter = "You have submitted a form with the content listed below. Your submission will be reviewed, please be patient in awaiting a response.


";
 else $messagetosubmitter = $_POST['messagetosubmitter'];

while(list($key, $value) = each($_POST))
{
 if (!stristr($controlvars, ' '. $key .' '))
 {
  $messagetoadmin .= $key .': '. $value .'

';
  $messagetosubmitter .= $key .': '. $value .'

';
 }
} 
$submitter = $_POST['submitteremail'];
if ($submitter == '') $submitter = 'enquiry@blue.co.uk';
if (strstr($submitter, "\n") || strlen($submitter) > 50) die("Begone, foul spammer.");

if ($usesecimage)
{
 $curr_path = getcwd(); 
 chdir($usesecimage);        // Go to the WSN directory 
 require 'start.php'; 
 if (isset($_REQUEST['seed'])) $seed = $_REQUEST['seed']; else $seed = false;
 $correct = securityimagevalue($seed);
 if (strtolower($_POST['securityimage']) != $correct) die("You did not type the value from the image correctly. Press the back button.");
 chdir($curr_path);      // Return to original directory 
}

   session_start();
   if(empty($_POST['TermsOfBusiness']))
   {
    error_reporting(0);
    echo "You must agree to our Terms of Business. Please <a href='javascript: history.go(-1)'>click here</a> to return to the form";
   }
   elseif(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) {

      mail("$adminemail, terry@blue.co.uk", 'Form Submitted: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($messagetoadmin), 'From: '. $submitter);
      unset($_SESSION['security_code']);

   } else {
      error_reporting(0);
      echo "The security code you entered was incorrect, please click the back button on your browser to try again.";
   }

if ($_POST['ccsubmitter'] == 'yes')
{
 mail($submitteremail, 'Form Submitted: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($messagetosubmitter), 'From: '. $adminemail);
}
if ($autoresponse != '')
{
 $body = geturl($autoresponse);
 mail($submitteremail, 'Re: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($body), 'From: '. $adminemail);
}
header('Location: '. $_POST['thankspage']);
// just in case redirect doesn't work
die('<meta http-eqiv="refresh" content="0;url='. $_POST['thankspage'] .'">');

if (!function_exists('geturl'))
{
function geturl($url)
{
 if (extension_loaded('curl')) 
 {
   $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.02; PHP)';
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);  // timeout after 5 seconds
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);  // timeout after 5 seconds   
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
   $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
   curl_close ($ch); 
// curl_error($ch); // for debugging
   return $result;  
 }

 if (version_compare("4.3.0", phpversion(), "<"))
 { 
  $filecontents = @file_get_contents($url);
 }
 else
 {
  $fd = @fopen($url, 'rb');
  $filecontents = "";
  do 
  {
   $data = @fread($fd, 8192);
   if (strlen($data) == 0) 
   {
    break;
   }
   $filecontents .= $data;
  } while(true); 
  @fclose ($fd);
 }
 return $filecontents;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: thsi file looks like it handle the form more than it generates it

Comment: you should mask email adresses when posting to a public forum!

Comment: There not the real addresses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(empty($_POST['TermsOfBusiness']))
   {
    error_reporting(0);
    echo "You must agree to our Terms of Business. Please click here to return to the form";
   }
```

This block checks Terms of Business as required. You can simply duplicate it while changing the input's name:

```
  if(empty($_POST['Marketing']))
   {
    error_reporting(0);
    echo "(Place here your text for Marketing checkbox validation). Please click here to return to the form";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sorry I've changed my mind is can this be an optional field?

Comment: I'm getting this warning but I have ticked the box?

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/sites/site.co.uk/public_html/mailer.php:1) in /home/sites/site.co.uk/public_html/mailer.php  on line 47
You must agree to our Terms of Business. Please click here to return to the formOpt in to recieve Marketing Data. Please click here to return to the form

Comment: `        <?php
$adminemail = 'lis@blue.co.uk'; // type your actual email address in place of you@yourdomain.com`. session_start() should be the *first* instruction you execute in your script. And yes, that error occurs because you have data printed (spaces, I might guess) before the session_start(). Place that command on the first line and delete those spaces from your script. That should make it work.

Comment: If you want it as an optional field, simply don't throw an error, regardless of its value.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the inputform, this script handles the input from the form.

Comment: Thanks i know it isn't input html is easy I want to know how to edit the php so it recognises this field as a required one please.